# Linegoal in (scr)book

Tags: linegoal

Linegoal calculates the wrong remaining line width when using the `book` or `scrbook` document classes.
This problem does not happen with `article` etc.

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{linegoal}

\begin{document}
\overfullrule=5pt % To show the overfull lines

some line \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content}

\clearpage

some different line \parbox[t]{\linegoal}{some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content some parbox content}

\end{document}
```

Result on page 1:
[image]

Page 2 is fine:
[image]

I think I narrowed it down to occur when there are different `\evensidemargin`/`\oddsidemargin`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out after sinking way too much time into this...

### tl;dr Fix

Add this to your preamble (after loading `linegoal`):

```latex
\makeatletter
\let\Z@E@linegoal\relax % undefine the property
\zref@newprop*{linegoal}[\linewidth]{\dimexpr
   \linewidth -\the\pdflastxpos sp
   +\ifodd\c@page
      \oddsidemargin
   \else\evensidemargin
   \fi
   +1in+\hoffset
   \relax
}% linegoal zref-property
\makeatother
```

Note that this may lead to an endless loop of changed labels if a page break depends on a `\linegoal` and the `\linegoal` itself is moved across pages due to this. In such cases, you may have to adjust the page breaks manually.

### Background

Basically, `linegoal` uses an internal counter `\LNGL@unique` that is increased by one at every `\linegoal` occurrence.
The current value of this counter is used to create labels (in the `aux` file) that look like this:

```latex
\zref@newlabel{linegoal/posx.3}{\page{35}\posx{19599809}}
\zref@newlabel{linegoal.3}{\linegoal{\dimexpr \linewidth -19599809sp +\evensidemargin +1in+\hoffset \relax }}
```

In this example, the value of `\LNGL@unique` was `3`.

The example also already hints at the problem: Page 35 is an odd page, yet we see an `\evensidemargin`.
However, the `linegoal` package doesn't just assume `\evensidemargin` everywhere; it checks whether the page number is even or odd and uses the corresponding margin:

```latex
   \ifodd\zref@extractdefault{linegoal/posx.\the\LNGL@unique}{page}\c@page
      \oddsidemargin
   \else\evensidemargin
   \fi
```

... to get the number of the page on which a `\linegoal` is located, `linegoal` uses `\zref@extractdefault{linegoal/posx.\the\LNGL@unique}{page}\c@page`, i.e., if there is a label `linegoal/posx.<counter value>` in the `aux` file, then it extracts the page from there, otherwise it use the current page counter value (`\c@page`).

However, for some reason, the current value of `\LNGL@unique` is almost always wrong,¹ and hence, the returned page number is wrong (from the second LaTeX run onwards).

¹: You can try for yourself by editing a copy of `linegoal.sty` and, e.g., replace the code snippet shown above by

```latex
   \ifodd\zref@extractdefault{linegoal/posx.\the\LNGL@unique}{page}\c@page
      \oddsidemargin + \the\LNGL@unique pt
   \else\evensidemargin + \the\LNGL@unique pt
   \fi
```

then look at the produced labels in the `aux` file.

### The Fix

Instead of relying on `\zref@extractdefault` (and thus the apparently wrong `\LNGL@unique` value), the proposed fix always uses the page counter.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!
I guess for my use-case (putting long comments within `algorithmic` environments that almost always live on their own page into `\parbox`es) that wasn't a problem (I have several tens of pages of such algorithms without any issues).
I guess I'll have to dig deeper then....

Comment: I'm not saying you're wrong, but for me, it _does_ work without any issues. Since my patch does not modify how `linegoal` creates labels, I can verify the correct selection of odd/evensidemargin by looking at my `aux` file after a couple of LaTeX runs and compare the selected offset with the corresponding page reference (due to the high number of such labels in my document, I checked this with a small python script).

Comment: actually I may be wrong, I'll delete the comments as I have no time to check now. the first comment is true that c@page can't be tested in the page but I think I missed you are testing this within the zref label so (I think) it's already delayed to shipout,  I'd have to check what zref is doing exactly